# Unable to see Internal app on Google Play for Nokia Android box

Tags: google-play, google-play-internal-testing

Device : Nokia Android Box

Precondition:

> Internal app is uploaded to track.
> Tester mail id is added
> Same tester mail id is logged in Nokia box

Issue : Not able to see Internal Build in Google Play page in Nokia box.
The page says **Beta** , but it lists only the Live app and not the Internal version.

Can someone help me with any cues. Thanks

[image]